# Hiding push events from dashboard

Tags: permissions, gitlab

I'm trying to setup access to a project in GitLab for a client.  However, I only want them to be able to access the issues section i.e. to be able to see tickets and create new ones.  This I believe is achievable by adding them as a Guest to the project.  However, when I login with the user's account, they can still see all the push events on the dashboard.  Is there any way to hide the commit messages or this entire widget?

Comment: Honestly, that sounds like a bug, or feature request.  I'm not sure you'll find an 'answer' on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @StevenV thanks for the comment.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't being completely dumb and missing something obvious

Comment: User "privileges" are included in [ability.rb](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/models/ability.rb). read_project gives access to project's homepage which includes a list of commits. Changing this would require some ruby hacking. Maybe you could start a feature request on http://feedback.gitlab.com/